# How can I know if I'm getting a 200 code response from an API with Jest before my project uses it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, testing, jestjs

Basically I am starting with Jest and I want to know with this tool if an API returns a response with status code 200. I have searched many ways to do it on the internet but none of them worked for me and I kept getting errors.

Could someone give me a hand on that?

For example, make a Rick & Morty API call with either Axios or Fetch and see if it returns a 200 status code:

https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character

I tried something like this:

File `mock.js`

```
const getMovies = async () => {
    try {
        let res = await axios.get('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character')
        return res
    }

    catch(error) {
      console.log('Error! D:')
      return error.response
    }
}


export default getMovies;
```

File `mock.test.js`

```
import axios from 'axios';
import getMovies from './mock.js';


jest.mock('./mock.js');

test('should return a 200 status code', async () => {
    const res = await getMovies()
    expect(res.status).toBe(200)
})
```

And it shows me the following:

[image: Result]

I want to know when my aplication receves a correct answer (a 200 status code) from the API to start to work normally.

Answer (score -1):

Try it

```
axios.get('/foo')
  .catch(function (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      console.log(error.response.data);
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log(error.response.headers);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Sorry, but it does not work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).